# Send a .csv file using Requests 2.2.1 in Python 2.7.6

Tags: python-2.7, file-upload, python-requests

I have to send a small .csv file to a partner server using the API they provide. I'm using Requests 2.2.1 in Python 2.7.6 and I have a working example in PHP. I can't put much more information but I was wondering if somebody could see what is the issue based on the output of my erroneous code (in Python) and the output of the working code (in PHP)

This is a trimmed down version of what I have, based on the doc of Requests to send a file ([POST a Multipart-Encoded File](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file))

```
import os
import requests

filecontent=open(filename,'r').read()
r=requests.post( url
               , data={'sessionId':sessionId, 'source':'Neurotracker'}
               , files={'files': (os.path.basename(filename), filecontent, 'application/octet-stream')} )
print('response text=[{}]'.format(r.text))
```

This is the kind of output I get

```
response text=[{"status":"error","error":{"descr":"Unknown error in FACTS file save path - sites\/default\/files\/facts\/csv\/2015\/04 _FILES is = 
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [name] => 344_2015-04-08T145040.csv
            [type] => application\/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => \/tmp\/phpW6jG0w
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 223
        )
)","number":106}}]
```

This is a working example in PHP

```
$post = array(
    'sessionId' => $sessionId,
    'source' => 'Polar',
    'files[factfile]' => '@' . $file_name_with_full_path
);


$ch = curl_init();
// May want to have error checking code for the init. 
// 
// note order is important. POST opt sett must come before POSTFIELDs, according to docs...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
// You should have some error handling for the result. One option is to print_r($result,true); dpm($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

And here would be the output of a good file upload

```
Array
(
    [files] =\x3e Array
        (
            [name] =\x3e Array
                (
                    [factfile] =\x3e 344_2015-04-08T145040.csv
                )
            [type] =\x3e Array
                (
                    [factfile] =\x3e application/octet-stream
                )
            [tmp_name] =\x3e Array
                (
                    [factfile] =\x3e /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpQfSVVK
                )
            [error] =\x3e Array
                (
                    [factfile] =\x3e 0
                )
            [size] =\x3e Array
                (
                    [factfile] =\x3e 223
                )
        )
)
```

I've noticed that all sub-keys of [files] are arrays in the output of a good file upload while mine isn't. So I've tried the way to send multiple files using Requests ([POST Multiple Multipart-Encoded Files](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files))

```
r=requests.post( url
               , data=payload
               , files=[('files', (os.path.basename(filename), filecontent, 'application/octet-stream'))] );
```

Without more luck.

I have the feeling that Requests might not be able to achieve a file upload in the expected format by the API; that would be with arrays in the sub-keys of [files].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit of black magic to me but all that was needed was to change `'files'` to `'files[factfile]'`:

```
r=requests.post( url
               , data={'sessionId':sessionId, 'source':'Neurotracker'}
               , files={'files[factfile]': (os.path.basename(filename), filecontent, 'application/octet-stream')} )
```

Anyone wanting to comment an explanation on why this worked is welcomed